Is there a list of IANA time zone to ISO Country Code and Region Code mappings?
Im looking to map IANA time zones to ISO country codes + region codes (where applicable). Is there some resource that has this mapping available for consumption? A c# package would be fantastic
I saw there were some resources like the IANA tz database and Time Zone Converter, but these were limited to just country codes. I would like region ids if available.
I also understand that IANA is trying to stay away from political boundaries and that I may get multiple time zones per region etc
